# Swiper Js Vue3 Vertical

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, swiper.js, nuxtjs3

I am having an issue with the swiper vertical, when I swiped once it goes to the last slide instead of the next slide.

I am using vue3, typescript, and swiper vue.

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue'
import 'swiper/css'

</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <swiper
      :direction="'vertical'"
    >
      <swiper-slide class="h-screen bg-yellow-100">
        1
      </swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide class="h-screen bg-green-100">

        2
      </swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide class="h-screen bg-orange-100">

        3
      </swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide class="h-screen bg-violet-100">

        4
      </swiper-slide>
    </swiper>
  </main>
</template>
```

Any help would be appreciated...